# Is there any api for dashboard analytics data?

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

Is there any way i can query in my app for data from the analytics tab of  dashboard?

For example:

```
ref.on("value", function(dashboard) {
 console.log(dashboard.concurrentUsers)
});
```

Comment: In your js console, you can using one of the ordering functions: `orderByChild()`, `orderByKey()`, `orderByValue()`, or `orderByPriority()`. You can then combine these with five other methods to conduct complex queries: `limitToFirst()`, `limitToLast()`, `startAt()`, `endAt()`, and `equalTo()`. For more details, please refer here:https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-queries

Answer (score 40, accepted):

From the "dashboard.concurrentUsers" in your question, it looks like you're trying to get the data from the **Analytics** tab of your dashboard.

As of Oct/Nov 2020 there is an [Analytics Data API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/trusted-testing/analytics-data) that you can use to run Analytics reports and retrieve data

You *can* also [enable the BigQuery integration](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics#integrations_with_other_services). Doing this means that all Google Analytics for Firebase events from that moment on will be written to BigQuery, where you can query them. This is the raw data, the events written by your apps, and not the aggregated data that you find in the dashboard.

Comment: Hi Frank, Is there any plans to provide API for Firebase Analytics? We are interested in aggregated data.

Comment: Has google yet provided public api to firebase analytics data ?

Comment: Hi Frank  Is there any way to get google playstore app details

Comment: This answer is two years old by now. Has this changed in the mean time (2018)? Cheers!

Comment: they at list add a deletion method lately to help us with GDPR:https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9019185?hl=en&ref_topic=6317497

Comment: Any follow up on this? Still no API? @epologee

Comment: There is no API for getting the analytics data from the Firebase console. **If** this changes in the future, I'll update this answer.