# How to get an export of firebase analytics full historic data?

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I have setup Firebase analytics data to BigQuery. However I received my first export today and it contains all yesterdays user statistics. That is great but I need lifetime statistics history or at least last month's data.

1. Do I already have access to my entire historic analytics data threw Big Query but I and I do not know how to access it? If so can you point to documentation or give a quick walk threw?
2. Is it even possible to get the full (or at least a longer period than a day) historic analytics data?

Bonus question: Can I directly access data that is used in Firebase analytics console? They should be feeding it with some API for some things I need aggregates would be sufficient. So is there http://analytics.firebase/data.json I could access while logged in to my Firebase account to save data to my machine?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*firebaser here*

Firebase Analytics does not expose the historical event level data. It only exposes aggregate information.

Complete event data is only available from the moment you enabled the BigQuery connection. No data from before that time will be added to BigQuery.

The data from the analytics reports that is shown in the Firebase Console is available through the Analytics Data API. See [Is there any api for dashboard analytics data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35095707/is-there-any-api-for-dashboard-analytics-data)