# Bigquery backfill table from Firebase Analytics

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I've just registered for the Blaze plan in BigQuery and linked my firebase project.

I see my analytics tables created for the last few days, however my app (that generates the analytics data) has been running for at least 20 days now, so i'm trying to query ALL my data.

I read online that there is a **backfill** option for transfers but i can not see any transfer in the console that is pending for my analytics data (though i'm pretty sure i could see that when i initially linked the project but now i guess it was completed and is not shown anymore)

How can i instruct BigQuery/Firebase to export all available data? (i don't really care if the existing two days tables get deleted/recreated)

Comment: Analytics data will only be added to BigQuery from the moment you connect the Firebase project to BigQuery. There is (as far as I know) no way to get analytics events from before that. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44364683/how-to-get-an-export-of-firebase-analytics-full-historic-data/44364830#44364830 If you found somewhere that this is possible, please provide a link to that source.

Comment: Such a shame.... So all my data that i've accumulated before the BigQuery link is essentially... useless as i can't access it in BigQuery.