# How to get app's old analytics data from firebase to bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery

How to get app's old analytics data from firebase to BigQuery? For example, my firebase analytics data is present from oct 2019 but i connected to BigQuery in may 2020, so currently i am only able to get the data from May 2020 not from Oct 2019

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, as per today, it is not possible to backfill all the historical data from Firebase into BigQuery because Firebase does not store raw events indefinitely and the data is exported into BigQuery from the moment that the link between Firebase and BigQuery is set.

There are other Stackoverflow threads where this issue is also discussed:

- [Bigquery backfill table from Firebase Analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54165023/bigquery-backfill-table-from-firebase-analytics?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [How to get an export of firebase analytics full historic data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44364683/how-to-get-an-export-of-firebase-analytics-full-historic-data)

Comment: Yes, your right  even i got the same reply from support team too.