# Firebase Analytics Export Missing Period & other issues

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I appreciate it if you can assist me with the following issues with Firebase Analytics export to BigQuery.

1. Data export was working correctly until Dec 29 2019 and after that, it's stopped due to storage limit and unfortunately, the tech team didn't take action. Recently we upgraded to Blaze Plan on Jul 05 2020 and the data export resumed but we have a gap in bigquery datasets from Dec 29, 2019, to Jul 04, 2020, if the data still at Firebase then why is not moving to bigquery?
2. We noticed Bigquery changed it's behavior how it's displaying the dataset, it records and shows data per Day instead as a single dataset covers all days. In this case if we need report for last 7 days we have to read from 7 datasets instead of one. please correct me if I am wrong.
3. How we can exclude Web+App & GA data from storing at bigquery. What we need to store is the Firebase Events only.

Your help is highly appreciated. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Let me address your concerns.

1. Data is only exported to BigQuery from the moment you create the export onwards. It follows the same behavior when the export stops and resumes later on. Meaning, historical data from Firebase Analytics cannot be currently exported to BigQuery. You can check several other posts that handle this issue. For example “[How to get an export of firebase analytics full historic data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44364683/how-to-get-an-export-of-firebase-analytics-full-historic-data)” or “[How to get app's old analytics data from firebase to bigquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62632873/how-to-get-apps-old-analytics-data-from-firebase-to-bigquery)”
2. Partially true, the export indeed sets up daily syncs of your data from your Firebase project to BigQuery. But, you should have 7 different tables (one per week day) which should be in the same dataset.
3. By default all apps send data, as stated in the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/bigquery-export#enable_bigquery_export). Follow [these guidelines](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6318765#manage) to manage which apps send data to BigQuery.

---

Comment: thank you so much for your helpful reply, I will consider them for sure.

Comment: If the answer was helpful please consider accepting it so that it will be more easily found by others with similar issues. Thanks!