# Is it possible to refill intraday tables into BigQuery from firebase?

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery

I'm using streaming data exports from firebase to bigQuery and it's working fine, yesterday I excluded events from the data by mistake so yesterday's table 20230207 came with missing events. is there any way to refill this table on this specific date back to bigQuery with the updated events settings

I tried to look if there is a manual option to refill that table, but didn't find

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to retrieve historical data from Google Analytics.

Also see:

- [How to get app's old analytics data from firebase to bigquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62632873/how-to-get-apps-old-analytics-data-from-firebase-to-bigquery)
- [How to get an export of firebase analytics full historic data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44364683/how-to-get-an-export-of-firebase-analytics-full-historic-data)