# Firebase Analytics doesn't export events table to Bigquery, even though streaming export is enabled

Tags: google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I'm trying to export my Google Analytics data from Firebase into Bigquery.

About 3 weeks ago the connector in Firebase was enabled with the "Streaming" export setting.

Just recently I decided to check BigQuery to start making some views and noticed that there is only 3 weeks' worth of "intraday" tables, which I understand are staging tables of sorts.

However, as per the documentation, there should also be another another table containing all the data simply called "events_", but these are completely missing:

> "You should query events_YYYYMMDD rather than
> events_intraday_YYYYMMDD"
> https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9358801?authuser=0

Where is the "events_" table? Is it safe to use the event_intraday tables instead despite what the documentation says?

Comment: Data is only streamed from Firebase to BigQuery from the moment you enable the integration. There is no way to get analytics data from before you enabled the integration.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get an export of firebase analytics full historic data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44364683/how-to-get-an-export-of-firebase-analytics-full-historic-data)

Comment: Getting historical data isn't my primary concern, l will edit the question. The issue is that the documentation states: "You should query events_YYYYMMDD rather than events_intraday_YYYYMMDD". However there are only event_intraday tables when I check Bigquery. I'm wondering where the other table is and/or if I could use event_intraday instead.