# When you send a message to a group from firebase console there is no statistics

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-analytics

I've created a group of devices ([FCM Device Group](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/device-group))

And when I send a message from the console the Sent, Open, and Conversion statistics are always 0.

[image: Send to group]
If I send a message to a single device the statistics works OK:
[image: Send to device]

Is there any way I can get Sent, Opened an Conversion statistics of a message sent to a group?

Can I retrieve those statistics via API?

I need to retrieve the opened and conversion data of different messages (Topics don't fit our needs). I can make it one by one or by groups, but I don't find how can I get the data.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Regarding the statistics (which is a part of Google Analytics for Firebase) -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/35097892/4625829

Comment: Thanks AL. that don't measure the impact of a single message. I found the answer through topics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have confirmation from Google that Statistics won't show in your console.

You can do it by subscribing devices to topics, form server side you can add your devices to topics [(documentation from Google)](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server#manage_relationship_maps_for_multiple_app_instances)

Then just send the push to the topic from console and you will have statistics.

Note that new topics will take up to 1 day to be shown in console.

I hope that helps someone.

Comment: Topics are immediately usable for sending messages, but will usually be visible in the console after 24 hours. :)