# Is it possible to embed Firebase Analytics data from my apps into a webpage?

Tags: firebase, embed, analytics, backend

I've searching a lot about someway to embed Firebase Analytics from my apps data into the backend UI from my website.

Is it possible to automate this process through some specific API methods to show those metrics from my Firebase Apps (like the number of installations or even the audience data)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

**Update**: There now *is* an API to retrieve the analytics report data. See my answer here for details: [Is there any api for dashboard analytics data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35095707/is-there-any-api-for-dashboard-analytics-data)

The other two options are:

1. Use the "Export to CSV" option for the analytics in the Firebase console.  [image] This is a manual operation though, there is no public API.
2. Link your Firebase project to BigQuery, to automatically export the data and then use for example Data Studio to generate the charts you want.