# How to get report from Firebase analytics using Firebase admin API

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics, firebase-admin

I am using node js Firebase SDK.
How can I access analytics data from Firebase, with the help of Firebase admin API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**: there **is** now an API to get the Analytics reports data. See my answer here: [Is there any api for dashboard analytics data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35095707/is-there-any-api-for-dashboard-analytics-data)

You *can* also:

- download the analytics report data from the Firebase console by clicking the <kbd>Download CSV</kbd> option from the <kbd>⠇</kbd> overflow menu. Also see my answer here: [Is it possible to embed Firebase Analytics data from my apps into a webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49733491/is-it-possible-to-embed-firebase-analytics-data-from-my-apps-into-a-webpage)
- connect Firebase Analytics to BigQuery to export the raw events, and query them in BigQuery, or visualize them with Data Studio.