# Firebase analytics from remote REST API?

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

Is it possible to have Firebase analytics hook into a remote REST API endpoint?

More concretely, suppose I have a remote REST API, with an endpoint that computes the average number of videos each of my users has uploaded, `/api/videos/get_average_count`. Can I somehow integrate that statistic into Firebase analytics? (I don't think there is a reporting API in Firebase analytics?)

Alternatively, is there anyway, I can take the Firebase data from the other analytics (tracked at the frontend) and integrate/embed that data into my own custom admin hosted on my own backend?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no available REST API where you can upload, download or even analyze analytics data. You could reach out to the [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support/) team and file a feature request for this. I believe that it's not only you who's looking for this kind of functionality in Google Analytics for Firebase.

You could directly download your event's analytics data as CSV using the Firebase console. Or, if you're on a blaze plan, [link your Firebase to BigQuery](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6318765?hl=en), and the analytics data will be exported to a corresponding data set in a daily basis.

Answer (score 5):

This is now in the early stages of being possible with [Measurement Protocol (Google Analytics 4)](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4/sending-events?client_type=firebase) but it's literally in the process of being rolled out as we speak. I have implemented server-to-server events to my iOS firebase data stream. Example curl-like request.

```
Faraday.new(url: "https://www.google-analytics.com/mp/collect?firebase_app_id=#{your_app_id}&api_secret=#{secret_from_ga4_stream_details}").post do
  req.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
  req.body = {app_instance_id: firebase_instance_id, user_id: user.id, events: [{}]}.to_json
end
```

This is a slightly different signature from a standard G4 property where the query params include measurement_id and client id. For firebase project you pass **firebase_app_id** which you get from your firebase project settings. **firebase_instance_id** is something you're probably not familiar with and something you will have integrate from device to the backend. For example, the instance id from ios would be `Analytics.appInstanceID()`

Comment: any API to fetch the analytics data ?

Comment: @AbishekKumar: that would be the Analytics Data API. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35095707/is-there-any-api-for-dashboard-analytics-data

Comment: Is there a way to fetch event data generated by Firebase Analytics, that I can use to send the event to third-party tracking solutions? How do you populate the body of your request?

Comment: @Ryan, can you explain why we need the instance ID when we use it in the cloud function? I want to create a server side logging in my cloud function and there is no Instance ID. How is the right way to log it from the cloud function? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The following curl command will log to Firebase analytics.

```
curl -v -X POST \
  'https://www.google-analytics.com/g/collect?v=2&tid=YOUR-MEASUREMENT-ID&_dbg=1&cid=YOUR-CID&en=testing&ep.origin=firebase' \
  -H "Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8" -H "sec-fetch-mode: no-cors" -H "sec-fetch-site: cross-site" -H "sec-fetch-dest: empty" \
  -H "pragma: no-cache" -H "cache-control: no-cache" -H "origin: http://localhost:3000" \
  -H "content-length: 0" -H "accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9" -H "accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br" -H "user-agent: dummy"
```

There are two things you need in order to make this curl command work:

1. You need to provide a value for the `tid` URL parameter. You should use the `measurementId` for your Firebase project. This [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/get-started) tells you how to get that.
2. You need to provide a value for the `cid` URL parameter. If you’re just testing things out, you can find this by looking at the requests the Firebase JS SDK sends from the browser in the network tab and copying the cid from one of them. Note that the `cid` will be included as a cookie in requests made to your web server, so when actually logging from your server you should get `cid` from that cookie.

You should be able to translate that curl command into code in the server language of your choice. For more info about this approach, check out https://pencilflip.medium.com/using-firebase-analytics-server-side-64ffacafa6c3.