# GET Firebase Statistics via API

Tags: firebase, api, firebase-analytics

I am looking for an automated way to pull down the some of the high level usages statistics via an API or persistent csv location with credentials.

You can see that the [linked image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0L2xT.png) that firebase provides a 'data-export.csv' file, under the Analytics menu .

Is there a way to do this, either directly from Firebase via an API, or via an integration with Google Analytics (I assume is the backend to firebase analytics), or via say a clever python script?  Reason being is we want to share some key info in organisational business intelligence reports.

I have scanned the forums without a clear solution or no its not possible.  Any assistance or examples of success (or failure) experiences and approach would be appreciated? Thx

Comment: There is no public API to get Analytics data from Firebase. The options are to manually export the CSV from the console, or enable BigQuery integration and then get it from there. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50355752/firebase-analytics-from-remote-rest-api

Comment: Thanks Frank - I did find some of those earlier posts but the post dates were old.  I see you are an engineer at firebase google - so thats pretty definitive. Much appreciated the quick response.

Comment: Hi @FrankvanPuffelen, since this post is for 7 months ago, I was wondering whether it is possible as of now to access Firebase 'web+App' analytics dashboard or event's data from python (with a Service account key json file)? I really appreciate your help on this one.

Comment: My answer here shows the API that now allows this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35097892/209103, which even seems to have a Python SDK: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1#python

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen sorry for the late response, Thank you. I follow the other thread and I could finally made it work!!

Comment: Great to hear @SaeidHedayati 