# Firebase Analytics graphs in Angular

Tags: angular, firebase, graph, analytics, dashboard

Is there any way I can display all the **graphs** available on my **firebase analytics** page, on my **angular dashboard**, by Using some kind of iframe or anything? if anyone has done anything like this, or there is a way to do it, it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend using an iFrame, as it comes with problems which can be read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23178505/good-reasons-why-not-to-use-iframes-in-page-content).

You could use the API to get access the data and display it yourself. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50355752/firebase-analytics-from-remote-rest-api)