# Connect Google Analytics 4 in a mobile application without Firebase

Tags: android, ios, firebase, google-analytics-4

We want to connect Google Analytics 4 to our mobile applications (Android and iOS)
All documentation that we found about this topic mentioned doing it through Firebase.
We checked on GA4 documentation and they always mention using Firebase: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9304153#zippy=%2Cios-app-or-android-app

Do you know if it is feasible to connect a mobile application to Google Analytics 4 without using Firebase?

Comment: There is a REST API nowadays. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/35097892/209103 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/64764917/209103