# how to get firebase analytics using ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, firebase

I have a mobile app (android and IOS ) integrated with firebase and it is already published on play store and app store and as a backend developer I need to get the firebase analytics using ruby on rails. How could I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no API to get the charts generated by Firebase Analytics. See [Is there any api for dashboard analytics data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35095707/is-there-any-api-for-dashboard-analytics-data)

As answered there, you can enable Firebase's integration with BigQuery to send all analytics events to BigQuery, where you can query them. But note that this is the raw analytics events, not the aggregated data that you see in the Firebase console.