# How To Fetch Firebase Analytics User Data In Angular Application

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire, firebase-analytics

I am working in Admin Panel which is being developed in Angular 11.

**What is my requirement?**
My requirement is fetching user actives like (user count, screen view first login, etc).

**How am I achieving that?**
I am using angular firestore npm library (AngularFire) tried to log the event and for fetching data and showing data but it is not working after going through their doc's it is the most likely the reverse approach where if a user views my screen or login it is updating the count in the panel.

**What am I looking for?**
Guys are there any way I can retrieve the data in the angular app using the same (AngularFire) npm package, or there is any other way around for achieving it.

thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 2):

Since late 2020 there is an [Analytics Data API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1) that allows you to retrieve report-level data from analytics that were reported through Firebase. I doubt this is wrapped in AngularFire at the moment though, so hav a look at the documentation to see how it works and post a question with a [repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you get stuck.

Also see:

- [Is there any api for dashboard analytics data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35095707/is-there-any-api-for-dashboard-analytics-data)

Comment: Thanks for sharing valuable resources Frank. I will try it out let you know