# How to retrieve data from firebase analytics in react native app?

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-analytics, analytics, firebase-analytics

I want to use react-native-firebase package to include firebase and firebase analytics in my react native app. It's  mentioned in the document  how data can be sent but I want to retrieve the sent data that will be sent in the firebase analytics in my mobile app. Does anybody know how this can be achieved?  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, definitely. Easy. Two steps:

First, you [link a GA4 property to FB](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9289234?hl=en).

Then you either [export the GA4 data to BQ](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9823238?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article) and then do with it what you will OR you go through a more painful (but cheaper) path of exporting it through the [GA4's reporting (data) api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1).

You can also just [link the FB to BQ directly](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6318765#zippy=%2Cin-this-article), but you get a bit more potential capabilities when you do it via GA4. Capabs like including more sources in the project without having to adjust the ETL (too much).

Finally, this question is probably a duplicate of another, but I noticed it too late: [Is there any api for dashboard analytics data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35095707/is-there-any-api-for-dashboard-analytics-data)

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for the answer.could you tell me If I link fb directly to BQ how can I retrieve that data in the app? I can see there is BQ integration option available in the fb how that data can be retrieved  with the app? If possible please share a link or something that I can refer. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's usually odd and unsafe to query your analytics data in an app. BQ is a remote SQL DB. You connect and query it as any other remote SQL DB. If you're gonna go that route, then the difference between using the BQ versus GA4 reporting data is not significant, so you may as well just use GA's reporting API. GA basically took the API and the data model from Firebase, so now behind the scenes Firebase is the same as GA4.